# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure and No Route to Host Connect Exception in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have installed mysql 5.7.2 on my Windows 10 PC and I have written a code in Eclipse to connect to mysql.Below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "shruthi@123";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }1

}
```

But i am getting a exception like java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host:

Can anyone help me it will be of great help,and i have already turned firewall off.

Below is the Exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:342)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at JDBC.main(JDBC.java:13)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301)
```

Please Help me with the above Exception

Thanks in Advance.